# Partitioning Database Relations by Hashing

Tags: database, memory-management, database-design, hash

From the textbook "Database System Implementation, 2000 Garcia-Molina and al.", section 6.6.1 Partitioning Relations by Hashing depicts the following algorithm for partitioning a relation R into M-1 buckets where M is the size main memory buffers (assuming one block is equal to one main memory buffer in size) :

```
initialize M-l buckets using M-l empty buffers;
FOR each block b of relation R DO BEGIN
     read block b into the Mth buffer;
     FOR each tuple t in b DO BEGIN
              IF the buffer for bucket h(t) has no room for t THEN
                  BEGIN
                      copy the buffer to disk;
                      initialize a new empty block in that buffer;
                  END;
             END; 
             copy t to the buffer for bucket h(t);
     END;
END;
FOR each bucket DO
     IF the buffer for this bucket is not empty THEN
          write the buffer to disk;
     END;
END;
```

I would love to know what do we mean by bucket in this context and how its structure looks like (a sketch will be more than appreciated)?
From what I have understood so far a bucket is one memory buffer that contains the hash key (i.e. h(t)) + value (i.e. t). However, we should not consider that one memory buffer which would fit for one block of tuples would fit as well for one bucket relative to this block due to the extra information provided by the key h(t). Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

In general, when talking about hash algorithms, a bucket is a “place” where an element should be placed according to the hash function. So a bucket is uniquely determined by the unique integer (address) returned by the hash function.

In the algorithm specified in the book, M is the number of bucket used (for instance, M is a prime number and the hash function is just the remainder of the division by M of the key, which is in this case is the whole tuple), and the buffers are used as intermediate memory to hold the pages of each bucket.

In the following picture (where B is used instead of M-1) you can see the process described in the algorithm:

[image]

The left cylinder is the input file, divided in pages (blocks) of tuples. The central rectangle represent the process of hashing all the tuples of a block, by writing them in one of the main memory buffers (that, when full, are written to the output, the right cylinder, to the corresponding bucket). From the picture it should be clear what is a bucket in this context: is a set of pages (blocks), and so it can be considered a file. Remember that the algorithm describes only the first pass of a two pass process: the distribution pass. The second pass will read, for each bucket, all the pages in the main memory, and will scan them to eliminate duplicates with an algorithm described in a previous section of the book (for instance with the use of a second hashing function).

Finally note that the main assumption is that only two passes are sufficient to process the entire initial file. In effect this is usually the case when the number of buffers in main memory is sufficiently high (with something like one hundred buffers the algorithm could process millions of tuples).